# Can i have a Carbon date as a constant in my class?

Tags: php, date

When i try to do this:

```
class {

const THIS_YEAR_START = Carbon::now()->startOfYear();

}
```

I get this error:

```
syntax error, unexpected '(', expecting ',' or ';'
```

Comment: No! Quoting from the [PHP Docs](http://uk1.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.constants.php): `The value must be a constant expression, not (for example) a variable, a property, or a function call.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is PHP constants are supposed to be a constant expression.

Assuming you are not on shared hosting and have composer installed.
run in terminal

```
composer require nesbot/carbon
```

Do something like this instead:

```
<?php
namespace Carbon;
require './vendor/autoload.php';


class myClass {

    public $year;

    public function __construct(){

            $this->year = Carbon::now()->startOfYear();

            }
    public function getYear(){

            return $this->year;

            }
    }



$i = new myClass;

print $i->getYear();


?>
```

The way I wrote this will allow you to add arguments later on if needed.

Comment: @RaheelKhan I wrote in the very first line of my answer why he got is error. You can refer to the php docs http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.constants.php